# Could not locate module @@/umiExports mapped as:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, umijs

I'm running to this error:
`Could not locate module @@/umiExports mapped as:'[Myrootdirectory]\node_modules\umiExports.`,

I'm using 'Umi.js' library with 'Jest' unit tests, all my unit tests are working fine both but yesterday I created this test which wouldn't run correctly it shows the error shared above
this is my new unit test file inside folder structure: `src/pages/Admin/components` which already contains some other tests that are working fine:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Customers from '../Customers';

jest.mock('umi-plugin-react/locale');

const mockedDispatch = jest.fn(() => {});
const Customer = {
  list: [],
  currentCustomer: {
    id: 'f6cf775f-0770-45af-0869-08d842b30965',
    createDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
    createdByUser: null,
    updatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
    updatedByUser: null,
    useDefaultFrontEndSettings: true,
    useDefaultEmailTemplates: false,
    useDefaultGeneralSettings: true,
    name: 'SalesLabNordic',
    displayName: null,
    address1: null,
    address2: null,
    postalCodeID: 0,
    phone: null,
    contactEmail: null,
    contactPerson: 'Søren Lundsgaard Jensen',
    webSite: null,
    cvr: 0,
    bankName: null,
    regNo: 0,
    accountNo: 0,
    swiftCode: 0,
    ibanNo: null,
    signature: null,
    companyLogoImageUploadFileId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
  },
};

describe('test customers component', () => {
  const renderElement = (
    <Customers.WrappedComponent dispatch={mockedDispatch} customer={Customer} loading submitting />
  );

  it('should render properly', () => {
    shallow(renderElement);
  });
});
```

my config files:
`jest.config.js`:

```
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  testMatch: ['**/src/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/src/**/*', '!**/src/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  globals: {
    __UMI_HTML_SUFFIX: false,
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/$1',
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', './'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["/src", "/test", "/mock", "./typings"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "tslint:latest",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ]
}
```

`jsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "checkJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the bunch of answers found on the internet, such as :
changing the `moduleNameMapper` part of my 'jest.config' by adding the path in my `tsconfig`
as follows:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '@/*': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/$1',
  },
```

still didn't work for me at all.